# How to refactor a controller with lots of watches

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller with lots of watches (only shown one here) and i want to move the watch code/logic outside the controller to make it thin. See the code below. The commented out portion below (//This works) vs the the one i have now doesn't wor. I am unable to access the money.a and money.b once the function definition is moved out of the controller. (I am using John Papa style guide and thats why i am watching on trade.money.b and not vm.money.b)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl as trade">

    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="trade.money.a">
        <input type="text" ng-model="trade.money.b">
        <input type="text" ng-model="trade.money.c">
    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', [])
                .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

                    var vm = this;
                    vm.money = {};
                    vm.money.a = 4;
                    vm.money.b = 5;

                    //This works
    //                $scope.$watch('trade.money.b',function(newVal,oldVal) {
    //                    vm.money.c = 2*(vm.money.a + vm.money.b);
    //                });

                    //This does not work
                    $scope.$watch('trade.money.b',updateQuant);
                });

        function updateQuant(newVal,oldVal) {

            //vm is not defined.
            vm.money.c = 2*(vm.money.a + vm.money.b);
        }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The updateQuant function should be defined inside the controller function, not outside. But I don't see how that eliminates a watch.

Comment: Also of note, the John Papa style guide recommends controller as syntax and avoiding inline anonymous functions.